# parsing Pipe Ini with Java

Tags: java, ini

I have an ini file that has some data that is separated by pipe. I want to read in the file and then set key,value to a string or something with java.

I was using ini4j but everywhere I look in order to parse the ini file you need to have something with sections my file does not have it the data looks like this

4800-722|4800 Logics
4800-723|4800 Logics
4800-743|4900 Logics
4900-745|4900 Logics
4900-746|4900 Logics
4900-786|4900 Logics
4800-C41|4900 Controllers
4800-C42|4900 Controllers

I want to take this and for example put the first one as a key then the second as a value like hashmap. The problem I am having I cant find how to parse this ini file like that everything I see you should use sections and get something from the sections. I cant move this to a text file this is a file that lives on the server and I have to use it. Any help would be appreciated I just have this so far

```
Wini ini;
     try {
      ini = new Wini(new File("C:/toolbox/settings.ini"));



     } catch (InvalidFileFormatException e) {
      System.out.println("Invalid file format.");
     } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("Problem reading file.");
     }
```

Comment: Your file does not look like valid INI to me. Are you sure it is adhering to the "standard"?

Comment: yes I actually ftped it from the server to my machine and opened it with notepad that is how I am trying to test it with using ini4j

Comment: I don't see what ftp or a server have to do with whether the file is in an actual INI format. As you said the INI format expect sections marked with brackets and key-value pairs separated by an equal sign. Your file has none of that

Comment: I am wondering If  i can just treat this just like a txt file. then do a split on the pipe.

Comment: Yes you can. It is a plain text file after all. File endings don't actually mean anything, they are just a convention (and help some programs to determine their format)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just read this as a text file and was able to parse out what I needed my code is below thank you UnholySheep.

```
  public static void LoadEtlData(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String file_name = "C:/toolbox/troux_etl.ini"; 
    ArrayList<String> records = new ArrayList<String>(); 

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file_name)); 
        String line; 
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            records.add(line); 
        }
        reader.close();
        System.out.println(records);


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

}
```